# Error 'Array to string conversion' when trying create hasMany relationship model laravel 10

Tags: php, laravel, orm, model, has-many

Here is my code in model Pos
` /**

```
 * Get all of the details for the Pos

 *

 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany

 */

public function details(): HasMany

{

    return $this->hasMany(PosDetail::class, ['session_id', 'branch_id', 'strukno']);

}`
```

And here is my code in model PosDetail

```
/**
 * Get the pos that owns the PosDetail
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function pos(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Pos::class, ['session_id', 'branch_id', 'strukdate', 'strukno'], ['session_id', 'branch_id', 'strukdate', 'strukno']);
}
```

What i try to get the data Pos is with this code
`$post = Pos::all(); return $post;`
That code is work in laravel 9, but not with laravel 10. Any different syntax between ver. 9 and 10?

Answer (score 0):

**The `hasMany` and `belongsTo` methods in Laravel only support a single foreign key, not an array of keys.**

So it should be like this

```
public function details(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(PosDetail::class, 'foreign_key_in_pos_details');
}


public function pos(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Pos::class, 'foreign_key_in_pos');
}
```

---

Ex: if you want to fetch data from `pos` with the `details` the.

```
$pos = Pos::find(1);

foreach ($pos->details as $detail) {
    // access the details here
    echo $detail->field;
}
```

or

```
$posWithDetails = Pos::with('details')->get();
```

Comment: But, why in my previous version it works with array and without a single foreign key?